How to list objects in Cloud Storage that are not folders in GCP?
I need to list all the files in a Cloud Storage bucket, in order to read the metadata and perform some action depending on those values. So, I have this code as a base:
func (c *CloudStorage) DeleteExpiredFiles(
    ctx context.Context,
    bucket string,
) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*20)
    defer cancel()

    errors := make([]error, 0)
    it := c.client.Bucket(bucket).Objects(ctx, nil)
    for {
        attrs, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            errors = append(errors, err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(attrs)
    }

    return nil
}

The problem is that I get, for example, these results:

1/
1/test/
1/test/october/
1/test/october/data.csv

I'm only interested in the file 1/test/october/data.csv since the others are just folders. I could do it simply with strings.HasSuffix from the standard library, but I think there must be a way to achieve this with the SDK, however I have not been able to achieve it.

Try https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#Query with a false IncludeFoldersAsPrefixes

@Volker Keep bringing them all :/

Maybe you can try with https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get? It returns an attribute with a file name.
I'm not savy with Go but here is an example of how to retrieve metada of an object. Maybe that helps?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/main/storage/objects/get_metadata.go

The problem is that this works to fetch the metadata of a specific object (with its name). My service simply receives a bucket name and must check all the files. For the moment I will use strings.HasSuffix, I have not found anything in the Google API that works for me :/.

Use the Query instead of nil with the following options:
    it := c.client.Bucket(bucket).Objects(ctx, storage.Query{
        Delimiter: "/",
        MatchGlob: "**?",
    })

Note, the docs specifically state:

To use matchGlob to filter for prefixes, delimiter must be set to /. Object prefixes always end with /, so glob patterns that match a trailing / (for example, **/) can be used to filter results to object prefixes only. Glob patterns that match a trailing ? (for example, **?) can be used to filter results to objects only.


I thought it would work but it didn't :/. With this configuration, it doesn't bring me any objects. (That is, it doesn't bring 1/test/october/data.csv either)

It worked for me leaving only the Match Glob (without the delimiter parameter). Thanks, your answer put me on the right track!
